# How do I change $PATH and set it to the default directory?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

For some reason when I run `echo $PATH`I get the following directory: `/Users/<home>/Library/Applications/`.

How do I set it back to its default location so that I don't have to run this command, `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` each time I want to run commands in Terminal?

Thanks for the consideration

Comment: What is in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

First, check the contents of your `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` for any lines involving writing paths to $PATH.

If this doesn't help, check the contents of `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` for any path that you don't want to be included in your $PATH.

Furthermore, you can show what code is being run by bash by adding the following to the top of `/etc/profile`:

```
set -x
```

Save the file, then open a new Terminal window. This should show when and how the $PATH variable is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have this file: `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`
That file can be used to set environment variables for OS X applications, not just shell commands. If the `PATH` variable is being set in that file you will get all kinds of wonky behavior. This [Apple Technical Q&A document](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa1067/_index.html) leads me to believe the environment.plist file has been deprecated. In nearly every case you do not want this file anyways so if you have consider deleting it.